# Has netflix released vhs-style box sets of stranger things seasons 2, 3 or 4?

Tags: stranger-things, merchandise

As part of the ramp-up to season 2 of *Stranger Things* there was a release of VHS-styled DVD sets for *Stranger Things* season 1; I purchased a copy at Target. I went looking recently to see if similar boxed sets have been released for later seasons, and all it appears that I can find are sketchy multi-region DVDs that reviewers suggest are pirated.

[image]

Did Netflix ever release licensed box sets of later seasons?

Comment: Betamax or GTFO

Comment: They did for [season 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K9PBLBS).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "vhs-styled dvd sets"? VHS is an analog medium; DVD is a digital medium.

Comment: @shoover The box is styled like it's a vhs cardboard sleeve, (notice it also has VHS branding in the lower right hand side), even though inside it has dvd/blu-ray disks (notice the sticker in the upper right hand side). It's Styled like it were a vhs, but is actually a dvd set.